# Selenium Ide: [error] Element css=div.alert.alert-success not found

Tags: javascript, css, selenium-ide

I am using selenium IDE. I need to verify that a flash message that is shown after successfully filling in data and clicking the save button.

I am using `assertText  css=div.alert.alert-success × Successfully updated your information` syntax

I get the error below

```
[error] Element css=div.alert.alert-success not found
```

Does anyone know why I am seeing the error.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  You don't need to thank people for helping (you can do that by up-voting or selecting their answers.  You also don't need to sign each post with your name.. you're user name is automatically added.

Comment: Please show your code. Also, Selenium IDE is not able to interact with Flash.

Comment: Using bootstrap? try div.alert-success

Answer (score 0):

The alert wasn't visible at the time that the line was executed.

When the alert is for sure present, execute:

```
<tr>
    <td>verifyVisible</td>
    <td>css=div.alert.alert-success</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

if that evaluates to true, you know you are using a valid css selector. Then try this for your test:

```
<tr>
    <td>waitForVisible</td>
    <td>css=div.alert.alert-success</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>assertText</td>
    <td>css=div.alert.alert-success</td>
    <td>Successfully updated your information</td>
</tr>
```